# How to format dates without the '0' in the beginning with Swift?

Tags: swift, date, format

I would like to format my dates to not have zeros in the beginning.
For example

```
04/03/20 -> swift should display as 4/3/20
```

I basically want to remove the zero that may be in front of the day, month, or year. The purpose of this is not for style purposes but for me to access data in a JSON. That's why it needs to be soo specific.

Comment: What is your input, a  `Date` or a `String`?

Answer (score 5):

You can get by using `Date` & `DateFormatter`

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"  // change formate as per your requirement
let date = formatter.date(from: "04/03/20") //change "04/03/20" to your input string

formatter.dateFormat = "d/M/yy"
let dateString = formatter.string(from: date!)

print(dateString) // 4/3/20
```

Comment: Thanks! I would look to use it for the current date though?

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = "04/03/20"

let parts = date.split(separator: "/")

var newDate = ""
for i in 0..<parts.count {
    newDate = "\(newDate)\(i == 0 ? "" :"/")\(Int(parts[i])!)"
}
print(newDate) //Result - 4/3/20
```